# Why do only the eyes on my character armature export incorrectly on FBX?

Tags: animation, armature, export, bones, .fbx

Basically, my character only has two meshes, the body and the eyes. I made sure that the bones are correctly named. Both eyes are named EyeMesh_L and EyeMesh_R. I also made sure to apply all the correct export conditions as shown in the screenshots. The problem I have is that the eyes end up exporting way above the character than in the place they're supposed to be. Any idea how to fix this pls? I'm trying to import this character to UE 2.6.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem! First, export just the model in its T-Pose or whatever your character's rest pose is, and then afterwards you can export the animations.

Answer (score 0):

So, I solved the situation somewhat by parenting the eyes to their respective bones rather than their bone relatives. The problem is that while the eyes are now position in the right place, they aren't moving with the idle animation. In Unreal Engine, it looks just fine, but in the T-Pose, the eyes are still off the chart. Some steps forward, but I'm still behind where I need to be.
[image]

[image]

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]